# Change cell group in sap.ui.table.Table

Tags: sapui5

I'm using the `sap.ui.table.Table` to build my table in a Fiori app. At this time I have loaded all the data from an OData service.
I have the following result:

[image]

Pressing the Competence Team I Group by this field.

[image]

As an example: I have searched and saw that it is possible, in the yellow part to put the sum of the cells that are below.
Example: In the column 4/1 for the AS group I have (0.00 + 0.00 + 0.00) = 0 and so on for the next live examples.
I know it's possible to put a footbar, but I think this is not adaptable for this example. 
Sorry if I do not explain the best way.

I am using version 1.28.

Answer (score 0):

Olá :) Check the guidelines for Analytical Table (ALV), at the "Agregation" section you can see details/info for to show/put totals to a selected column.

https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design/ui-components/analytical-table-alv/

Comment: In this case I can't use ALV because I'm using JSON for my data
Thanks for your time :)